# Philosophers who were composers?

Tags: music

Who are some famous philosophers who also composed music?

I can think of one example: [**Boethius**](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02610b.htm), [one of the first music theorists / acousticians](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DBoethius%2C%20Anicius%20Manlius%20Severinus%22) and author of [*Consolation of Philosophy*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/14328); he composed:

- [*Boethius: Songs of Consolation*](http://sequentia.org/recordings/recording31.html) ([YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-kjiI7V894&list=OLAK5uy_kykPHknTCleQNZ_CGrra-QgUw5D2BW87c))
  <sup>([source](https://forum.musicasacra.com/forum/discussion/16470/boethius-songs-of-consolation))</sup>

Comment: Nietzsche of course :)

Comment: @JosephWeissman Wow, I didn't know that. Apparently [he composed some piano works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYBwNcTeY7M), too.

Comment: Karl Popper composed some music.

Comment: Do you really allow list-questions here?

Comment: @pipe This site can unfortunately be quite lax with soft questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yeah, it's puzzling because both OP and the people who gladly answer the question all have pretty high reputation leading me to believe that it's accepted. I have no idea how one would accept the "best" answer here. Or maybe it's just that people are too slow casting close votes.

Comment: eh it's a fun question.

Comment: By the word 'composer' do you refer to an inventor of only music, or also to the words (songwriter)? I don't see that we have evidence that Boethius composed music. The music seems to have been added to his poems later.

Comment: @another_name Yep. A lot of questions are fun. Some will fit the Stack Exchange format. This one does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Nietzsche:

---

[Rousseau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau) wrote both the music and libretto for an opera - [Le Devin du Village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_devin_du_village).

[Rousseau - Le Devin du Village on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ld7XDELDnto)

---

[Adorno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_W._Adorno) was a classically trained pianist, studied composition with [Berg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alban_Berg) in Vienna, and wrote piano music and a number of string quartets.

[A selection of Adorno string quartets on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=adorno%20string%20quartet)

Comment: Did not know about Adorno!

Comment: @Conifold He fell under the spell of Schoenberg to compose music very much of the time.  I occasionally listen to Schoenberg, Berg, or Webern when I'm doing the dishes.  Seriously.  It works really well.

Comment: You might also add that Wagner was a composer who was a bit of a (racist) philosopher: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/62076/philosophers-who-were-composers

Comment: @BenHocking Wagner is an interesting suggestion, but perhaps more as a great composer who suffered a cranky dotage.

Comment: @Conifold: He tried to apply **rational** aesthetics via twelve-tone music. He even tried to be a critic of contemporary music. To be fair, I deem his music and aesthetic writings to be quite...erratic and special.

Comment: how derogatorily do you mean that @PhilipKlöcking ? his music criticism i thought was fairly well regarded considering how trenchant he was about stravinsky. i had copies of his music, but am no musician

Comment: i'm not even sure what people could be getting from adorno if they dispose of his aesthetics. a lot of nonsense about marx

Answer (score 3):

Gabriel Marcel according to Brendan Sweetman composed music:

> He also developed a keen interest in classical music and composed a number of pieces.

However, I could not find a list of these compositions.

---

Thanks to @sand1 from comments: "La Biblitheque Nationale Francaise list has a section for him as Compositeur(54) [data.bnf.fr/fr/11914394/gabriel_marcel](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/11914394/gabriel_marcel/)"

---

Sweetman, B. "Gabriel Marcel". Retrieved April 23, 2019 from *Britannica* https://www.britannica.com/biography/Gabriel-Honore-Marcel

Comment: La Biblitheque Nationale Francaise list has a section for him as Compositeur(54) https://data.bnf.fr/fr/11914394/gabriel_marcel/

Comment: @sand1 Thank you. I added that to the answer.